# After merging two branch and then rebuilding I am getting these errors related to Dagger/missing binding

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on a client project via GitHub, there is two branches let's say branch 1 and branch 2, and both are working perfectly separately, but when I merge branch 1 into branch 2 and resolve all conflicts and then after resolving all conflicts, i clean the project, sync it and then try to rebuild it then it is throwing some dagger missing error, i have tried everything but unable to solve it, as its a multi-module project, these are the following errors :-

```
D:\3.4)clientmainworkgithub\04)github_holedo_dev9_1pm_15may2022\matrix-sdk-android\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\org\matrix\android\sdk\internal\session\SessionComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] error.NonExistentClass cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface SessionComponent {
                ^
      error.NonExistentClass is injected at
          org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.crypto.crosssigning.DefaultCrossSigningService(…, outgoingKeyRequestManager, …)
      org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.crypto.crosssigning.DefaultCrossSigningService is injected at
          org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.crypto.crosssigning.UpdateTrustWorker.crossSigningService
      org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.crypto.crosssigning.UpdateTrustWorker is injected at
          org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.SessionComponent.inject(org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.crypto.crosssigning.UpdateTrustWorker)
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.SessionComponent.session()
      org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.SessionComponent.syncTask()
      org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.SessionComponent.inject(org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.room.send.SendEventWorker)
      org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.SessionComponent.inject(org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.room.send.MultipleEventSendingDispatcherWorker)
      org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.SessionComponent.inject(org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.content.UploadContentWorker)
      org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.SessionComponent.inject(org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.sync.job.SyncWorker)
      org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.session.SessionComponent.inject(org.matrix.android.sdk.internal.crypto.verification.SendVerificationMessageWorker)
```

Comment: Have you tried *clean project* and *invalidate cache*? If not try them first. If it still doesn't work I'd guess it is something wrong with your merging.

Comment: Please try this thread-https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1631 ,may be some annotation is missing in your class.

Comment: @abbas i have tried everything, but still not working

Comment: It is possible that you have a file with compile time error. You need to import the definition of a class. It can happen if you have the `optimise import` feature. Unfortunately you get the error with Dagger and you do not get the other.